# ZF2 Form and Doctrine 2 modify the value_options

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am using Doctrine 2 in my Zend Framework 2 Project. I have now created a Form and create one of my Dropdowns with Values from the Database. My Problem now is that I want to change which values are used and not the one which I get back from my repository. Okay, here some Code for a better understanding:

```
$this->add(
            array(
                    'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
                    'name' => 'county',

                    'options' => array(
                            'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
                            'label' => 'County',
                            'target_class'   => 'Advert\Entity\Geolocation',
                            'property'       => 'county',
                            'is_method' => true,
                            'empty_option' => '--- select county ---',
                            'value_options'=> function($targetEntity) {
                                $values = array($targetEntity->getCounty() => $targetEntity->getCounty());
                                return $values;
                            },

                            'find_method'        => array(
                                    'name'   => 'getCounties',
                            ),
                    ),
                    'allow_empty'  => true,
                    'required'     => false,
                    'attributes' => array(
                            'id' => 'county',
                            'multiple' => false,
                    )
            )
    );
```

I want to set the value for my Select to be the County Name and not the ID. I thought that I would need the 'value_options' which needs an array. I tried it like above, but get the

Error Message: **Argument 1 passed to Zend\Form\Element\Select::setValueOptions() must be of the type array, object given**

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to suggest modifying your code, although after checking the `ObjectSelect` code i'm surprised that (as far as I can tell) this isn't actually possible without extending the class. This is because [the value is *always* generated from the id](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineModule/Form/Element/Proxy.php#L502).

I create all form elements using *factories* (without the `ObjectSelect`), especially complex ones that require varied lists.

**Alternative solution**

First create a new method in the Repository that returns the correct array. This will allow you to reuse that same method should you need it anywhere else (not just for forms!).

```
class FooRepository extends Repository
{
    public function getCounties()
    {
        // normal method unchanged, returns a collection
        // of counties
    }

    public function getCountiesAsArrayKeyedByCountyName()
    {
        $counties = array();
        foreach($this->getCounties() as $county) {
            $counties[$county->getName()] = $county->getName();
        }
        return $counties;
    }
}
```

Next create a custom select factory that will set the value options for you.

```
namespace MyModule\Form\Element;

use Zend\Form\Element\Select;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;

class CountiesByNameSelectFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $formElementManager)
    {
        $element = new Select;
        $element->setValueOptions($this->loadValueOptions($formElementManager));

        // set other select options etc
        $element->setName('foo')
                ->setOptions(array('foo' => 'bar'));

        return $element;
    }

    protected function loadValueOptions(ServiceLocatorInterface $formElementManager)
    {
        $serviceManager = $formElementManager->getServiceLocator();
        $repository = $serviceManager->get('DoctrineObjectManager')->getRepository('Foo/Entity/Bar');

        return $repository->getCountiesAsArrayKeyedByCountyName();
    }

}
```

Register the new element with the service manager by adding a new entry in `Module.php` or `module.config.php`.

```
// Module.php
public function getFormElementConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'MyModule\Form\Element\CountiesByNameSelect'
                => 'MyModule\Form\Element\CountiesByNameSelectFactory',
        ),
    );
}
```

Lastly change the form and *remove* your current select element and add the new one (use the name that you registered with the service manager as the type key)

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'counties',
    'type' => 'MyModule\Form\Element\CountiesByNameSelect',
));
```

It might seem like a lot more code (because it is) however you will benefit from it being a much clearer separation of concerns and you can now reuse the element on multiple forms and only need to configure it in one place.

Comment: Woh, Thank you so much AlexP for your detailed answer. I had the same feeling that it was not possible, but would have not been able to point it out in the Sourcecode. Thanks for that. It's a shame that there seems to be no easier way, I think it should be possible to decide what you would like to pass. But anyway, I will try your solution and get back when I got it to work. Thanks again !

Comment: Alex this is far more suitable approach than my solution. Luka, sorry for misunderstanding. I just deleted my answer to prevent wrong orientation of newcomers.

Comment: No worries foozy, I did not explain it very well. Thank you very much anyway for your answer !

Comment: @AlexP, excellent, it works! Just 1 addition, you have to add ->setLabel('county') under // set other select options etc, otherwise it will throw an Error Message. Thank you so much again, that would have taken me ages to get it to work otherwise.

Comment: @AlexP, yes it's great. Now I only have to find out how to get to the next Step... via Ajax-> load the Towns (dependable Dropdown). I will try to follow the same concept for it and update my above Code, if I get it to work.

Comment: @Luka I would recommend keeping the question as is and ask another question if you get stuck as changing it may confuse others that are after a similar answer.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Just feel bad about asking multiple questions. Maybe I will find it out myself and I don't have to in the end ...