# Create a common country dropdown method in zend framework 2 (zf2)

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have created a custom commonlib controller class in Vendor/MyLibrary/MVC/Controller.

Now I want to write a method which will fetch all country related data from db and create a drop-down list, which I can call in all other class when required.

Other method working fine which I wrote in  commonlib class, but when I try to initialize adapter like this  $this->adapter = $adapter; its not giving any data.

Below is my code

```
namespace MyLibrary\Mvc\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
//use Zend\Session\Container;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Where;

class Commonlib  extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function __construct(Adapter $adapter) {
    $this->adapter = $adapter; 
    $this->initialize();
} 
public function getCountry() {
    $sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
    $select = $sql->select()
    ->from('country'); 



    $statement = (object)$sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
    $row = $statement->execute();
    //$row = $result->current();
    if (!$row) {
            return FALSE;
       }

    return $row;
 }
```

Any idea, where I am doing mistake?
Thanks,

Comment: It is totally **not** clear what you are asking. What is the situation? What do you aim to achieve? What have you tried? what is your exact problem? Can you make a small test case which explains your problem. I am unsure what Commonlib is, why it extends the AbstractActionController, why you directy wrk with Zend\Db in that class. It is so cluttered that it is hard to understand your goals.

Comment: Hi Jurian, I have a class in  Vendor/MyLibrary/MVC/Controller/commonlib.php and I have a db table called country and field 'Id', 'countryname'. Now I want to connect db and fetch data from db on commonlib.php page itself. I have db credentials in global and local.php file.

Comment: Turn it into a repository, encapsulate the SQL and return its result to the callee.

Comment: I couldn't understand your solution, sorry. can you please tell me how I can established db connection in a file which is present in  Vendor/MyLibrary/MVC/Controller/commonlib.php here. I don't want to create model for this. This commonlib.php is a single page file. where I can have all my extra method. and I can call it as per my requirement in my model. Sorry for my bad explanation, if I am still not clear.

Comment: @JurianSluiman is correct; your question is unclear and perhaps your understanding of ZF2. If you want a 'dropdown' [you should be creating a `Zend\Form\Element\Select` object, injecting it's 'country' options by querying a repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365559/zf2-form-and-doctrine-2-modify-the-value-options/27376232#27376232). This form and it's elements would then be rendered in the view.